# Initializing the web worker with Typescript and NextJS

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, web-worker

I am trying to use web worker with typescript and nextJs. Using webpack 5
The worker is initialized like this in the worker-client.ts:

```
import WorkerFile from "worker-loader?name=static/[hash].worker.js!../workers/worker";

export const WorkerClient = () => {
   const worker = new WorkerFile();
   const communicate = () => {
      worker.onmessage = (evt) =>
        alert(`WebWorker Response => ${evt.data}`)
      worker.postMessage('Hello John');
   }
}
```

Worker is defined as follows (worker.ts):

```
export default {};

addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("worker event message", event.data);
  postMessage(event.data);
});
```

Worker-loader file is defines as follows(web-worker.d.ts):

```
declare module "worker-loader?name=static/[hash].worker.js!*" {

 class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
  }

  export default WebpackWorker;
}
```

This is the configurations added to `next.config.js`

```
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.worker\.ts$/,
      loader: 'worker-loader',
      options: {
        name: 'static/[hash].worker.js',
        publicPath: '/_next/'
      }
    })

    config.output.globalObject = `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this)`

    config.plugins.forEach(plugin => {
      if (plugin.definitions && plugin.definitions["typeof window"]) {
        delete plugin.definitions["typeof window"];
      }
    });

    return config;
  }
```

Getting the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/worker-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/workers/my.worker.ts
Error: MainTemplate.hooks.hotBootstrap has been removed (use your own RuntimeModule instead)
```

According to this [issue](https://github.com/dromru/encoding-plugin/issues/116), this should be fixed with webpack 5. Any idea on this?

Comment: Have you checked out [the official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-web-worker/utils) on this? [Since webpack-5, Next.js has native support for web workers.](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5) So you probably don't need to manually configure worker-loader in your webpack config.

Comment: @brc-dd Checked the official example. I am trying to initialize the worker without using `useRef`. Initialized with `const worker = new Worker(new URL("../services/worker/my.worker", import.meta.url));`. Getting the same error.

Comment: any update here ? Did you manage to create service worker in typescript with next js. Please update us